# How to arrange 4 boys and 2 girls in a way that girls arent alongside each other.

Tags: combinatorics

we want to arrange 4 boys and 2 girls in a way that girls arent alongside each other.
a. How many arrangements can satisfy what I wanted
b. Is there a universal formula for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enforce that the girls are not adjacent to eachother, first arrange the boys.  Then pick spaces *between* the boys or to the far left or far right for the girls to be in.  For example, with boys $\color{blue}{1,2,3,4}$ and girls $\color{red}{A,B}$:

Start with as many empty spaces as there are boys.

$$\underline{~~~~}~~\underline{~~~~}~~\underline{~~~~}~~\underline{~~~~}~~$$

- Step 1: Arrange the boys in the four available spaces.  For example like so:

$$\underline{\color{blue}{2}}~~\underline{\color{blue}{1}}~~\underline{\color{blue}{3}}~~\underline{\color{blue}{4}}~~$$

Then put extra space between each and to either side:

$$\underline{~~~~}~~\underline{\color{blue}{2}}~~\underline{~~~~}~~\underline{\color{blue}{1}}~~\underline{~~~~}~~\underline{\color{blue}{3}}~~\underline{~~~~}~~\underline{\color{blue}{4}}~~\underline{~~~~}~~$$

- Step 2: Arrange the girls into the empty spaces with at most one girl per space.  This enforces the rule that no two girls sit next to one another.  For example as:

$$\underline{\color{red}{A}}~~\underline{\color{blue}{2}}~~\underline{~~~~}~~\underline{\color{blue}{1}}~~\underline{\color{red}{B}}~~\underline{\color{blue}{3}}~~\underline{~~~~}~~\underline{\color{blue}{4}}~~\underline{~~~~}~~$$

Removing the extra empty space leaves us with our final arrangement in our example as being $\color{red}{A}\color{blue}{21}\color{red}{B}\color{blue}{34}$

How many ways can each step be completed?  Applying multiplication principle implies what is the final total number of arrangements?

Do you see how this technique can be generalized to any number of boys and girls?

Answer (score 0):

Take the total number of seatings, and take away the number of seatings where the girls are sitting together. This gives you the number of seating arrangements where the girls are not sitting together.

Comment: Is there a universal formula? for 3 girls and 3 boys, I have found 4 for this by getting 6!/(3!*3!)-3!/2!*5!/3!*2!+4!/3!( sorry i don't know how to use mathjax its something i want to learn)

Comment: Not as easily generalizable.  To generalize with this method, one might decide to use inclusion-exclusion.  This would require a great deal of computation for, say, fifty boys and twenty girls which would not be feasible to do by hand.

Comment: so I can use inclusion-exclusion principle. I just wanted to learn if I can use it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please include what you have tried when you ask a question. This being said, let's proceed.

First we sit the boys, there are $4! $ ways we can do this. Now, since we want to find a way such that no girls sit next to each other, there are 5 places where the girls can sit (in between the boys or in one of the two ends). So the number of ways  the girls can sit will be $\binom{5}{2} \cdot 2!$. Hence the total number of ways is

$$4! \cdot \binom{5}{2} \cdot 2! = 24 \cdot 10 \cdot 2 = 480$$